# Organic Groups - Group members list (with content profile) with views

Tags: entities, organic-groups, users

http://ruh.kz/groups/ruhkz under the title - Участники группы - is placed a view block that displays members of this group. I've used a default view → og_recent_members, but it doesn't works for content profile. I need to display a CCK field from content_profile module.

Tried to set in filters - content type:profile, and in fields selected Content:field_photo, but it doesn't works. Displays nothing.

How to display CCK imagefield (Profile Photo) instead of usernames in og_recent_members views block?

Comment: Perhaps you need to add a relationship? Spitballing as I have not used OG

Answer (score 1):

In the view add a new relationship
1.) Select node and then content profile->corresponding content type, which creates a relationship.
2.)Now in the fields add your content profile fields u want to display. here select the relationship content profile.
Now you should have your profile fields coming from content profile.